# How to Implement User Account Switching in a Mobile DApp without Hardcod Wallet Private Keys?

Tags: wallets, ethereum-wallet-dapp, evm, smart-contract-wallets, mobile-wallet

I'm currently developing a mobile decentralized application (DApp) and I've had to hardcode the private key of the wallet to sign transactions. However, I'm facing a challenge when it comes to allowing users to switch between accounts, similar to what is typically done in web-based DApps.

I'm seeking advice on best practices or strategies to manage account switching in a mobile DApp with hardcoded wallet private keys. Specifically, I'd like to know if there are any established patterns or techniques for achieving this, while maintaining security and usability. Any guidance on how to implement this feature would be greatly appreciated.